# Not detecting a 404 in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app where I'm trying to redirect to a page if my API returns a 404 status code. I'm trying to capture the error in the following way and then if it is a 404, push to another page.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.memberInfo()
      .subscribe(res =>{
        this.user = res.json();
        console.log('The User: ', res.json());
        this.profileService.getProfile(res.json().id)
          .subscribe(res => {

            if(res.status === 404){
              this.navCtrl.push('CreateProfilePage');
            } else {
              this.profile = res.json();

              if(this.profile.first_name && this.profile.last_name)
                this.profileInitials = this.profile.first_name.charAt(0) + this.profile.last_name.charAt(0);
            }

          })

      })
  }
```

For some reason, this check isn't working and I'm not handling the error.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: add the whole script plz

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(res)` inside the subscribe?

Comment: Because I'm returning 404 status from my api, I get the following console results: Response {_body: "{"msg":"No profile found"}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: oh you need to add the handling part inside the catch parameter like so:
`this.auth.memberInfo().subscribe(res => {}, err => {
  //handle the error here
})`

Comment: Thanks, Hussein, that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do that is to use interceptors. Simply declare your interceptor like that:

**not-found.interceptor.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {ErrorObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req)
      .catch((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          this.router.navigate('/your-404-route');
        }

        return ErrorObservable.create(response);
      });
  }
}
```

Then provide it in **app.module.ts**:

```
providers: [
...
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NotFoundInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
...
  ],
```

Now for any HTTP call you send, if you'll get 404 back it will redirect user to your 404 page. You can use this approach for many things, like:

1. Unauthorize user on 401 response
2. Forbidden page
3. Global error handling
4. You name it :)